# Can't able to create id session on login in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am not able to create id session on login in codeigniter. It seems that i am doing something wrong. Although the (Session name) is working perfectly but (Session id) in not created

Here is model code:

```
public function login($username, $password){
    $this->db->select('name, password');
    $this->db->where('name', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get('suppliers');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $row = $query->row();
        $data = array(
                'id' => $row->id,
                'name' => $row->name,
                );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Controller Code:

```
 public function login(){
        $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
        $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));

        if($this->Supplogin_model->login($username, $password)){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'You are successfully logged in.');
            redirect("Supplier_login/supplierlogin");
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Sorry Unsuccessfull login. Try again.');
            redirect("Supplier_login/supp_login");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Select `id` in the `select` query as well**

```
public function login($username, $password){
  $this->db->select('id, name, password');
   $this->db->where('name', $username);
   $this->db->where('password', $password);
   $query = $this->db->get('suppliers');
  if($query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
    $row = $query->row();
    $data = array(
            'id' => $row->id,
            'name' => $row->name,
            );
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    return true;
  }
 return false;
}
```

**check for session `id` or `name` in controller :**

Controller Code:

```
    public function login(){
    $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
    $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));

    if( $this->session->userdata('id') ){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'You are successfully logged in.');
        redirect("Supplier_login/supplierlogin");
    }
    else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Sorry Unsuccessfull login. Try again.');
        redirect("Supplier_login/supp_login");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't able to login with `$this->session->userdata('id')` but able to login with `$this->session->userdata('name')`

Comment: this is because you r not selecting id in the select query